# How to create the binding file for changing complexType to simpleType

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd, xjb

I had a field in XSD schema:

```
<xs:element name="magicField">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:int">
            <xs:totalDigits value="8"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

In java class was generated a field:

```
int magicField;
```

But then, xsd schema has changed to:

```
<xs:element name="magicField">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:restriction base="int_code">
                <xs:totalDigits value="8"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Where "int_code":

```
<xs:complexType name="int_code">
    <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base="xs:positiveInteger">
            <xs:attribute name="name"/>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

And JAXB generates the following code:

```
MagicField magicField;
```

and MagicField.java in additional.

But I still need only

```
int magicField;
```

in generated code.
Attribute "name" won't be used at all.

**I can't change the schema, my way is only binding file (xjb).**

How I should create the binding to re-map "int_code" type and get "magicField" as simpleType (`int` in code), not complexType (`magicField` in code)?

As I understand I also need a custom XmlAdapter, not only binding rule.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following instead of creating a complex type int_code:

```
<xs:element name="magicField">
<xs:complexType>
    <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:positiveInteger">
            <xs:totalDigits value="8"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

Or a better way you can create a simpleType for magicField as below:

```
   <xs:element name="magicField">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:positiveInteger">
            <xs:totalDigits value="8" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for response, but I can't change the schema.